# JSESSIONID cookie sent by Weblogic is missing the last part

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

We are deploying our Java web app on Weblogic 12c (12.1.2.0.0). The value of the JSESSIONID cookie differs from the value in the server. The cookie has not the last part. This causes an error in one of our methods.

The value of the cookie:

```
1lPNJjJR-izDn1LQy8Lo69_jujcgCcBtPPCz9jS9zVkE2N4_m5JM!1969913142
```

And the value on the server for the same session:

```
1lPNJjJR-izDn1LQy8Lo69_jujcgCcBtPPCz9jS9zVkE2N4_m5JM!1969913142!1493733119155
```

The last exclamation mark and the following value are not present in the cookie.

We are aware of this format but why does not Weblogic send whole value?
Is this on purpose (a security measure for session fixation) or have we configured something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The session is identified by the part before the first exclamation point.
The values after the excalamation point are references to the WebLogic server that owns the session.
You can have up to three values after the first exclamation point depending on the replication of the session. These values can change via Set-Cookie header when the primary/secondary servers shuts down.